# How to extract energy from an alternating electric field?

Tags: ac, electric-field

Given an alternating electric field E inside e.g. a big parallel plates capacitor, how can you make use of the field's energy to power an electronic device?

So far I thought of putting two smaller unconnected parallel plates inside the field.

This however did not seem to work in a small experimental setup with ~230V / 50Hz yielding (theoretical) capacitor field strengths of roughly 11.5 kV/m and resulting in 0 V measurements across the smaller parallel plates.

**Edit: Actual dimensions and values added**
[image]

\$A_1 = 0.25m * 0.25m = 0.0625 m^2\$

\$A_2 = 0.1m * 0.1m = 0.01 m^2\$

\$d_1 = 0.02m\$

\$d_2 = 0.0016m\$

Peak electric field strength: \$\hat{E} = \frac{230V}{0,02m} = 11.5 \frac{kV}{m}\$

Big plate capacitance: \$C_1 = \frac{\varepsilon_{0}*A_1}{d_1} \approx 27 pF\$

\$X_{C_1} = \frac{1}{2\pi fC_{1}} \approx 115 M\Omega \$

Big to small plate capacitance (if small plates are centered): \$C_{1,2} = \frac{\varepsilon_{0}*A_2}{\frac{d_1 - d_2}{2}} \approx 9.6pF\$

\$X_{C_{1,2}} = \frac{1}{2\pi fC_{1,2}} \approx 330M\Omega \$

I have the feeling that I am missing something very basic here which results in those 0.00 V measurements.

**Edit**

Following these calculations, even at higher frequencies in the MHz range, the extracted energy would be waaay to small to power even small microcontrollers.

**What else can I do to extract energy inside a parallel plates capacitor with an alternating electric field?**

Comment: Your two additional plates form a capacitive divider in conjunction with the outer plates. Have you calculated the source impedance of such a divider @ 50 Hz? How does this compare with the impedance of your meter?

Comment: 2 kV/m suggests that your outer plates are about 10 cm apart. If they're one square meter in area, then you have a capacitance of roughly 90 pF between them, and roughly 6.5 uA flowing @ 230V/50 Hz. This should actually show a few volts on a 10 Mohm meter. However, if your plates were significantly smaller, then the voltage will be proportionally reduced as well. Plates of 0.01 sq. m would only yield millivolts.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the numbers on the first post. See my edited question with correct values above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given an alternating electric field E inside e.g. a big parallel
>   plates capacitor

Assuming 1 sq metre plates and 1 metre between the plates, there's a total parallel-plate capacitance of 8.85 pF. [Try this calculator to check](https://daycounter.com/Calculators/Plate-Capacitor-Calculator.phtml).

At 50 Hz the capacitive reactance is 360 Mohms so how much energy do you think you might get from two smaller plates on the inside? The smaller plates might be 0.1 sq metres and then the capacitance from an outer plate to a smaller inner plate will be 0.89 pF having a reactance of 3.6 Gohm. But there's two of them so that's a total series capacitive reactance of about 7 Gohms.

What were you expecting to see across your meter and were you in fact thinking that a capacitive transformer would result?

If the smaller inner plates were each 1 mm from their respective outer plates then the total capacitive reactance would be 7.2 Mohms and you would certainly see some voltage on your meter.

Comment: See my edited question above. I was indeed expecting to measure some reduced voltage across the smaller plates as they float at different electric potentials inside of the field. This was only an example i.e. an **idea** how to do the energy extraction. My main question "how to extract energy from the alternating electric field" still remains open :)

Comment: Your basic method is correct for removing energy but your implementation is weak. Higher frequencies and higher voltages are the way to improve things.

Comment: Okay, the actual system will run in the MHz range anyway, so I will look further in this direction.

Comment: After doing the math, I think the amount of received energy would be waaay to small to power even small micro-controllers. Do you know anything else what I can do to achieve at least < 1W of power-transfer?

Comment: Magnetic power transfer is the best method.